# Can't Authenticate through Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I currently force users to authenticate through Facebook each time they start a new session with my site.  This means I force users to hit the url obtained through $facebook->getLoginURL() each time the browser is restarted.

When a user completes the login process, they are redirected to my login script:

```
{checks for CSRF token and error status...}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '{my app id}',
    'secret' => '{my app secret}',
    'cookie' => true
));

//Get user info
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user)
  echo 'user found';
else
  echo 'no user!';
```

$user always results in 0; I am getting the expected 'state' variable and no errors in the API response.  Also, I see that the relevant App permissions exist on my profile.  However, $facebook->getUser() still returns 0.  Is there some intermediate step that I'm missing (am I expected to do anything with the user's auth token?)

I know there are many threads on this problem but haven't found any resolutions.  Also, I think this is a very basic example so I'm hoping the answer here will be more useful for future users dealing with the problem.  Thanks!